# How drunk is too drunk?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

Different drinks get me drunk at different speeds, is there any way of knowing how drunk a drink will make me? How drunk do I need to get before I become fall-down-drunk?

Comment: Are you falling down?  No?  You're not drunk enough.

Comment: nice tongue-twister :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The amount of Drunkeness you can have before becoming completely useless depends on your skills and what kind of run you are doing. For the purposes of normal ascensions, your alcohol tolerance runs at about a baseline 15. At and over that, you're face-down in the gutters. You can increase your tolerance by consuming a steel margarita, received from the Azazel in Hell quest.

Avatars of Boris and Zombie Slayers are lightweights, only having a tolerance of 5, while Avatars of Jarlsberg can handle slightly better at 10. Avatars of Sneaky Pete, on the hand, pretty much have two functional livers and have a base tolerance of 20.

Note that these numbers are the levels of Drunkenness *at which* you become falling-down drunk. The amount of alcohol you can drink and still actually adventure is the aforementioned appropriate number minus 1. So to more clearly illustrate my point:

- Normal ascension - 14 Drunkenness
- Avatar of Boris/Zombie Slayer - 4 Drunkenness
- Avatar of Jarlsberg - 9 Drunkenness
- Avatar of Sneaky Pete - 19 Drunkenness
- Actually Ed - 0 Drunkenness
- consuming steel margarita - +5 Drunkenness tolerance
- Nightcap (Avatar of Jarlsberg skill) - +5 Drunkenness tolerance
- Hard Drinker (Avatar of Sneaky Pete skill) - +10 Drunkenness tolerance
- Hollow Leg (Skill gained from Sloppy Jalopy) - +1 Drunkenness tolerance
- Replacement Liver (Actually Ed skill) - +5 Drunkenness tolerance

Answer (score 6):

The [kingdom of loathing wiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Martini) has a potency value for most, if not all, drinks, and it is visible in the item description.

[For a normal character](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Drunkenness) the maximum drunkenness without being fall-down-drunk is 14. So 15 and above is to much.
Getting a Liver of Steel increases your maximum safe inebriety to 19.

Comment: The potency can be seen in game too, if you open the details of the drink.

Comment: @Arperum Jeah was just double checking that, wanted to beat Sconibulus for once :)

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden monster :)

Comment: @Sconibulus hey at least I don't post my answer if you beat me to it =p

Answer (score 4):

You can get up to 14 drunkenness safely by default, and 19 if you get the liver of steel from the Deep Fat Friers side quest.

As a rule of thumb, beers and wines give you 1 or 2 drunkenness, spirits and basic mixed drinks give three, fancy mixed drinks(umbrella, coconut, etc) give 4.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you get the *falling-down-drunk* state when you have 15 or more drunkenness, but you can upgrade it to 20 by consuming a [Steel Margarita](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Steel_margarita) which is a reward for an optional quest.

You can see the amount of drunkenness you gain from a drink by looking at the "potency" in the item description. A general rule of thumb is:

- Beer: 1
- Shot of Schnapps: 1
- Pure Booze: 3
- 2-ingredient Cocktail: 3
- 3-ingredient Cocktail: 4

When you want to know the details about a specific drink, you can look up on [the wiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Drink_Categories).

Answer (score -3):

KoL Mafia has a great food and drink menu, where the fullness and drunkenness are listed along with the adv gained for consuming. A great tool for speed runs.

KoL mafia is a java program, that helps with planning and adventuring I the kingdom. It supports all kinds of scripts, to automate the tasks as well as a enhanced browser that displays combat info (think HP, at, def) quest items to collect etc. The link can be found here: [mafia](http://kolmafia.sourceforge.net)

The use of this tool is sometimes frowned upon, since you don't get to experience the unknown. I personally used it to automate my castle farming, and later to have softcore pull scripts.